# PHP - Finding and removing an XML node via DOM

Tags: php, xml

Can anyone please point out why the PHP below isn't deleting the XML node?

I'm wanting to delete the entire image node that contains the original_number value of 823.

Thanks in advance.

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<property> 
    <edited>true</edited> 
    <images> 
        <image> 
            <is_required><![CDATA[true]]></is_required> 
            <original_number><![CDATA[823]]></original_number> 
        </image>

        <image> 
            <is_required><![CDATA[true]]></is_required> 
            <original_number><![CDATA[555]]></original_number> 
        </image>
</images>
</property>';

$originalNumberToDelete = 823;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML( $xml->asXML(), LIBXML_NOBLANKS );
$dom->formatOutput = true;

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach( $xpath->query("property/images/image[original_number='".$originalNumberToDelete."']") as $node) {
$node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Comment: what is happening? error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a possible solution is to change

`$dom->loadXML( $xml->asXML(), LIBXML_NOBLANKS );`

to

`$dom->loadXML( $xml, LIBXML_NOBLANKS );`

Then start your xpath expression with a double forward slash:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<property>
    <edited>true</edited>
    <images>
        <image>
            <is_required><![CDATA[true]]></is_required>
            <original_number><![CDATA[823]]></original_number>
        </image>

        <image>
            <is_required><![CDATA[true]]></is_required>
            <original_number><![CDATA[555]]></original_number>
        </image>
</images>
</property>';

$originalNumberToDelete = 823;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML( $xml, LIBXML_NOBLANKS );
$dom->formatOutput = true;

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach( $xpath->query("//property/images/image[original_number='".$originalNumberToDelete."']") as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/JEFCI)

Comment: Thank you. Either single or double slash fixes the issue.

Comment: that's why I'm a fan of explanations in answers - besides code.